# I think I deleted my partition, but I can still see it in Windows 10 "disk management"

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, partitioning, disk-management, dualboot

Okay so, I downloaded on my Windows 10, Ubuntu and I successfully achieved a dual boot system with Ubuntu. Because I need to re-install Ubuntu, I wanted to delete it, from my windows. I found online that I can do it from "Windows 10 disk management". I deleted some partitions, but there are still some that I cannot delete. I am left with these:

[image]

When I try to delete one of them, I get his message:
[image]

I click yes and then I get
[image]

I don't get this, why it is in use?
[image]

I am beginner, so be patient.

Comment: Which partition are you trying to delete exactly.  I see an unallocated partition that’s 10 GB every other partition is required by Windows to exist

Comment: Yeap, I was about to say the same and add that 10GB is no enough for any modern Linux distro. 25GB-30GB is often recommended and much more is needed if you intend to install let's say Steam and some games.

Comment: I am a little bit confused, I thought that partitions :disk 1 : partition 4 5 6 etc are becasue of ubutnu. Are they supposed to be there ?

Comment: @ChanganAuto that's why I needed to delete ubutnu and reinstall it , because I realised that I did not give it enough space. but I thought it was easier instead of resizing it to delete it and reinstall it , but I messed up?

Comment: I'm not following your reasoning... Yes, you need more space for / and the only place it can come from is the Windows C:\, a problem because it has only 16% free space. Even assuming that what you want to do is advisable - it isn't, get yourself a bigger drive - why would it be easier to delete partitions in Windows? Now, shrinking any NTFS partitions should be done from Windows with Windows tools. Other than that GParted or even Disks in Ubuntu are much more sophisticated and versatile tools than Windows native Disk Management.

Comment: @ChanganAuto so  right now .. I am not sure what I deleted. The partitions I see , what are they? When I restart my laptop , I no longer have the option to boot into ubuntu as I can see

Comment: @brucebanner - They we’re created by Windows and they are required for Windows. DO NOT delete them. The limited space they would provide wouldn’t make a difference even if you did.

Comment: This ^^^. A 120GB SSD is barely enough for one OS, let alone two.

Comment: @Ramhound thank you that's what I needed to know.

Comment: @ChanganAuto is it possible to run my ubuntu on disk D instead? my C is not big but my D is 1 T (Iif you have to suggest me any article, I could not find something to make sense out of it)

Comment: Yes, it's possible but inadvisable because it's a slow HDD. And in any case it wouldn't be on D:\ but in the same drive containing the **partition** Windows labelled as D:\ (this letter convention is exclusively Windows and calling it "disks" is moronic and misleading)

Comment: You would have to create a partition on that disk since it’s currently NTFS and to my knowledge Ubuntu cannot be installed on a NTFS partition. You might want to look into running a Vm instead of installing Ubuntu on your system.  Dual booting can introduce some significant technical issues and limits, which are difficult to diagnose, if your not extremely familiar with Ubuntu, Grub, and Windows